# how to make constructor definition mandatory

Tags: java

I have an interface I that is implemented by a base class B. The base class is extended by a bunch of classes (A,C,D) that must init some of the protected vars declared in base class B. I'd like to make the declaration of a constructor mandatory in the subclasses (A,C,D), to discourage the user from relying on default constructor that's declared in B. Yet I *do* want the B's default constructor to execute automatically, since B can be used by itself as well. How can I accomplish this?

thanks

Comment: Your requirements are in conflict. On the one hand, it's absolutely necessary that the extending classes initialize certain class state. On the other hand, the base class can be used on its own. My question for you: why do you insist that subclasses initialize state that is clearly initialized perfectly well by the base class? Isn't that up to the subclasses? And if not, then why allow the base class to be instantiated at all?

Comment: No conflict at all.      Suppose my Interface is Vehicle, Base class is SportsCar by default has 4 doors, which can be further refined by F1Car (0 doors), MiniVanCar (4 doors + hatch), etc.

Comment: @Saideira That's fine. My point is that I don't see why you *insist* that subclasses change variables. In your example, `SportsCar` defines itself to have 4 doors. If I create the class `OffRoadSportsCar` which extends `SportsCar`, why should I have to specify the door-count again? It's done for me.

Comment: LOL even offroad cars have 4+hatch (Cherokee, Landcruiser) or 2 (Sahara/TJ/Rubicon) or even 2+h (Toyota FJ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an abstract superclass of B with a private constructor:

```
public abstract class BSuper {

    private BSuper() {
        // initialize stuff
    }

    protected BSuper(some params) {
        this():
        // other init with parms
    }
}


public class B extends BSuper {

     public B(some other params) {
         super(some params);
     }
}


public class A extends B {

     public A() {
         super(some other params);
     }
}
```

or similar

Answer (score 0):

Make B's default constructor private and call this(); from within the parameterized constructor...

```
public class B {
    private B() {
        super();
    }
    public B( Foo foo ) {
        this();
    }
    public static B createInstance() {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

Edit:  Miss read the issue, removed abstract keyword from class declaration.  Also added public static factory method for creating B class.  It calls B's default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a comment in the Javadoc that says "Use of default constructor is discouraged when subclassing." In my experience, trying to enforce that programmatically is not worth the effort and could cause problems latter on. Simple English will do.

Answer (score 0):

If class B is going to have its own default constructor, what you want is impossible.  When you derive from a class, you're telling the compiler that it should allocate memory for a base class object in every instance of the derived class.  There's no way to tell a java compiler to suddenly take away some of the base class's functionality every time that something is inherited from it.

Also note that constructors and static factory methods can't be abstract, so even if B could be an abstract class you would have to do something like:

```
public class B {

     B() {
          initialize();
     }
     protected abstract void initialize();
}
```

...along with making sure that the derived classes implement default constructors that call super()

Comment: This could create hidden bugs. From Bloch's Effective Java 2ed, Item 17: The superclass constructor runs before the subclass constructor, so the overriding method in the subclass will get invoked before the subclass constructor has run. If the overriding method depends on any initialization performed by the subclass constructor, the method will not behave as expected.